# How to define failed predicate in composite Guava predicate

Tags: java, guava

I have list of "User" validations to be performed, each validation implements Predicate (from Guava). I have following method which fills the List of validations to be performed and creates composed Predicate of all validations.

```
List<Validation> validations = new ArrayList();

Predicate<User> composedUserValidations;

private void setupValidations() {
    validations.add(userEmailIsValid());
    validations.add(userPhoneIsValid());
    validations.add(userLoginIsValid());
    .....
    //creating composite
    composedUserValidations = and(validations);
}
```

Question: when I will trigger apply to composedUserValidations and one of them will fail, is there a way to find which one exactly is failing.
Now I have:

```
public boolean isUserValid(User user) {
    if (!composedUserValidations.apply(user)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and I want to have something like:

```
public void validateUser(User user) {
    if (!composedUserValidations.apply(ticket)) {
        throw new ValidationExcepction("Predicate which failed");
    }
}
```

What will be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could design a builder for your `User` class, let's name it `UserBuilder`.

For each of the `User`'s properties (login, email, phone) in the builder class, you could not only provide the value you would like to set for the `User` instance, but also the `Predicate`, which you can immediately apply. If any of the predicates fail, you could easily throw an Exception and/or output a message, etc.

For all the instances you create, you could optionally pass different validation rules, or you could additionally design your builder to skip the validation for any of the `User` fields.

Example:

```
public class UserBuilder {

    private String phone;
    private String email;
    //add more properties here;

    public void phone(String phone, Predicate<String> phoneValidator) {
        if (!phoneValidator.test(phone)) {
            throw new UserBuilderException("Invalid phone provided");
        }
        this.phone = phone;
        return this;
    }

    public void email(String email, Predicate<String> emailValidator) {
        if (!emailValidator.test(email)) {
            throw new UserBuilderException("Invalid email provided");
        }
        this.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    //add more builder methods here

    public User build() {
        return new User(phone, email);
    }

}
```

You could use that with:

```
Predicate<String> phoneValidator = ....
Predicate<String> emailValidator = ....

User user = new UserBuilder()
            .phone("123567", phoneValidator)
            .email("something@example.com", emailValidator)
            .build();
```

What you get with that is:

- Flexibility to provide custom validation rules (or omit some of them) for each `User` instance you have.
- Better visibility about which properties fails their corresponding validation rules.
- No `User` instances created with invalid content. A `User` instance will be created only for the property tuples, which pass *all* the `Predicate`s provided in their builders.